# Unknown iPhone Control - Help me out

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

Hi can anyone let me know which control they have used for doing the scrolling.

I like that control very much.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ssa2k4RlYXs&feature=channel

Application is free to download. Help me to figure out which control is this.

Application URL: itunes.apple.com/us/app/xix-cwg/id353382539?mt=8

Help me out.

Control is inside: Schedule Tab in the application

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Arpan

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that video is just a UIScrollView. While it shares a lot of the properties of a `UITableView` you may notice that a `UITableView` is a subclass of a `UIScrollView`.

There are a number of ways to create that functionality. I recommend looking at the documentation for `UIScrollView`. You may be able to find some glue between a `UITableView` and a `UIScrollView`. If you decide to write your own `UIScrollView` subclass keep in mind memory issues. You will have to unload the "not visible" portions of the view if you are displaying a lot of data.

The `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol has the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method that you can use to do custom view layout as the view scrolls.

You can use the `contentOffset` property to get the position of what is being displayed in the larger scrollview.

I think you will find its not that hard, once you experiment with UIScrollView. Especially if you aren't planning on do any zooming.